# jQuery toggle/slide animate table body

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is what I want: `.mytbody1` slides up gradually and hides while `.mytbody3` comes out gradually and shows and vice versa on clicking the anchor link `.mytbody2`. The link also goes up and down as per the sliding.

I saw many examples here and tried them too but they are not working.

I am making some mistakes in jQuery and am not able to identify the correct syntax.

I have tried: `$('.mytbody1').animate{("height:toggle","duration:slow")};`.

But this does not work, what is the right way?

This toggles perfectly but I need it to slow down gradually.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $('.mytbody1').show();

  $('.mytbody3').hide();

  $('.mytbody2').live('click', function () {

    $('.mytbody1').toggle();

    $('.mytbody3').toggle();   

  });   

});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slideup/, http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery for slow slideToggle

```
$('.mytbody1').slideToggle('slow');
$('.mytbody3').slideToggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method:

```
$('.mytbody1').slideToggle();
$('.mytbody3').slideToggle();
```